# XPath : Names of all sibling nodes

Tags: xpath, siblings

I am unable to get the `following-sibling` axis to work.

I have an XML document as follows. I tried something like `name(/T/p/q/following-sibling::*[1]`. I know `name` would result only the first of the set, but, that expression does not return anything. I am trying the XPath with `xmlstarlet` command on Ubuntu.

```
<T>
<p><q>
<a1>A</a1>
<a2>A</a2>
<a3>A</a3>
<a4>A</a4>
<a5><b1>A</b1></a5>
</q></p>
</T>
```

Given input as `/T/p/q`, I want the names of all its child element nodes but, up to that level only. That is, the output should be

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's much simpler than you think.

```
/T/p/q/*
```

Returns a node-set of `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5`.

It selects all children of `q` which is a child of `p` which is a child of `T` which is a child of the `context node`.

And by saying "children", I mean "immediate children". Not "descendants". Therefore, it will only select nodes on the `a1-a5` level.

As you've said, the `name()` function only returns a name of the first node in the node-set. I guess that you'll have to traverse the node-set to get all the names as a single string.

---

Using `xmlstarlet`, you can do this:

```
xml sel -t -m "/T/p/q/*" -v "name(.)" -n input.xml
```

It matches the node-set, calls `name(.)` on every node in it and prints a newline afterwards.

- `-m` to match an XPath expression
- `-v` to print a value returned by an XPath expression
- `-n` for a newline
- [more here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s01.html)

---

To use `following-sibling` axis, you'd have to be on the same level, for instance to select all following siblings of `a2`, you'd use `/T/p/q/a2/following-sibling::*`. This would return `a3, a4, a5`.

Comment: Thanks, Slanec. How do I use `/T/p/q/*` to return me only the node names ? The `name` function would return only the first one ? As for your `following-sibling` example, the issue is, I wouldn't know in advance the name of first (or any) child of `q`. Sorry, I didn't clarify that earlier.

Comment: @cogitoergosum I updated the answer with a complete `xmlstarlet` query on getting all the names.

Comment: Thank you, Slanec ! It helped. @Dimitre Novatchev , I would have used your solution. But, my requirement was to wrap around the XPath in a SQL for a Derby database (which I did just now). Thanks, anyway !

Comment: @cogitoergosum And yet - the accept goes to Dimitre :). Anyway, I'm glad I could help, I had some trouble with `xmlstarlet` myself back in the day...

Answer (score 2):

**In XPath 1.0 it isn't possible to obtain the wanted all names of the children the elements `/T/p/q/*` by evaluating a *single* XPath expression.**

Therefore, all elements need to be selected in a first step:

```
/T/p/q/*
```

Then for each element contained in the resulting XmlNodeList, a new XPath expression, evaluated off that element, produces its name.

Different implementations of this algorithm are possible, using different hosting languages for XPath 1.0.

**Below is an example, where the hosting language for XPath 1.0 is XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vWanted" select="/T/p/q/*"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vWanted">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<T>
    <p><q>
    <a1>A</a1>
    <a2>A</a2>
    <a3>A</a3>
    <a4>A</a4>
    <a5><b1>A</b1></a5>
    </q></p>
</T>
```

**the two steps of the algorithm are executed and the wanted result is produced:**

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
```

---

**II. A Single XPath 2.0 expression - solution:**

```
/T/p/q/*/name()
```

The evaluation of the above XPath 2.0 expression produces a sequence of five items, each of which is the name of a different `/T/p/q/*` element.